# How to call a function from an interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I have a Angular 5 app, and I want to have an interface that defines a function such as this:

```
interface PersonInfo {
    getName(): string;
}
```

And I want another interface that will have a function that has one of its functions return a type of the above:

```
interface Parser{
    getPersonInfo(document: string): PersonInfo;
}
```

I want to then SOMEHOW use it in my main component, such as the below.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements PersonInfo, Parser {

    constructor() {
        const pi: PersonInfo = this.getPersonInfo('test');
        console.log(pi.getName());
    }
    public getName(): string{
        return 'getname';
    }
    public getPersonInfo(document: string): PersonInfo{
        const pi: PersonInfo  = {
            getName(){
                return 'getPersonInfo - getName()';
            }
        };

        return pi;
    }
}
```

The problem is that in `console.log(ci.getName());`, my site gives me an error of `TypeError: ci.getName is not a function`.

I'm not sure how to get the `getPersonInfo` to set the name... and then the `getName()` to return that name ... and then in the constructor (or in some other function) to call these functions and GET the name. Any help?

Comment: This might help: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/features/interfaces.html

Comment: show us `getContactInfo` method

Comment: console.log(this.pi.getName())? -add this-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is that you are asserting to TSC that the created "pi" object conforms to the "PersonInfo", but it's missing the "getName()" property.

Try this:

```
public getPersonInfo(document: string): PersonInfo {
    const pi: PersonInfo = {
        getName() {
            return 's';
        }
    };

    return pi;
}
```

When possible, avoid using the "foo as Bar" syntax, it seems to be an override to let developers cast a value to a type that the compiler can't guarantee is valid.